HTMLに埋め込んだGoogle Mapの上部に余白が生まれるのをなくしたい
ポートフォリオ用の架空のWebサイトを作成しています。
住所と埋め込んだGoogle Mapを横並びにしたいのですが、アクセス欄をdivで囲み display:inline を指定すると、添付した画像のように、地図が横には配置されますが上部に余白ができてしまいます。
画像内の矢印で示したように、Google Mapを「アクセス」に引いてある下線のすぐ下に持っていきたいのですが、どうしたらよいでしょうか？
試したこと
テキスト領域とGoogle Mapをそれぞれdiv領域で分けてcssでdisplay:flexを設定
→単純に横には並ぶがその後のmargin/paddingによる位置の調整ができない
<section id="access">
                <div id="whole_access">
                    <div id="access_text">
                        <div class="access_walk">
                            <h2>ACCESS アクセス</h2>
                            〒100-0005<br>
                            東京都千代田区丸の内1丁目<br>
                            さくらビル 1F<br>
                        012-345-6789
                        </div>
                        <div class="access_train">
                            <h3>電車でお越しの方</h3>
                            <p>JR「東京駅」中央口から<br>
                            徒歩5分</p>
                            <a href="shops.html"><img src="images/btn_search.png" alt="店舗検索はこちら"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="access_map">
                        <iframe
                        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.833233678314!2d139.764510611904!3d35.68110807247296!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1730344013228!5m2!1sja!2sjp"
                        width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                        referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

/*各メイン領域見出し下の線を引く*/
section h2 {
    border-bottom: #413330 solid;
}

.access_walk h2 {
    width: 721px;
}

/*アクセス欄の住所の下に点線*/

.access_walk {
    border-bottom: #413330 dotted 1px;
}

/*埋め込み地図の大きさを調整*/

iframe {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#access {
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: block;
}

.access_train img {
    width: 250px;
}

#access div {
    width: 300px;
}

#whole_access {
    display: inline;
}



「試したこと」のdisplay:flexの方針で良いと思います。padding/marginの調整も何とでもなるはずなので、padding/marginで何が実現できなかったかをメインの質問にするのがいいかもしれません。
